# rake aborted // ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: database configuration does not specify adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

This is happened when i type in ubuntu bash " rake db:create"
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPjzL.png)

Who knows what i can do with this...

I using windows with ubuntu bash.
Installed postgresql ruby and ruby on rails.
Its my database.yml:
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjMNZ.png)

Comment: Do not use images to show error messages -- add the error text to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using sqlite3 or another database engine. As far as I know that is only a file that is created with a new rails app.